# How do I ascertain whether an equation defines a function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Asides from graphing an equation are there any other ways of determining if an equation is a function?

Comment: However it may be difficult sometimes, using the definition is a routine way,i.e., $a=b\to f(a)=f(b)$.

Comment: I think he means something like $\frac{x+y}{x-y}=2$ - is $y$ a function of $x$? @BabakS.

Comment: @Assad The terminology of your question is imprecise. Technically, an equation is never a function. An equation can be used to define a function, however...

Comment: You may look for “implicit defined functions.”

Comment: I've edited it, i hope it reads better now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can re-write the equation as a dependent variable and a independent variable, so Y = an equation only involving X, then verify that each X determines only 1 value for Y (i.e, there are no $\pm$ or you don't need to take even roots of Y to isolate it etc.)

Answer (score 0):

An equation in two variables (call them $x,y$) implicitly defines a set of tuples $(x,y)$ that satisfy it.

A set of tuples can be thought of as representing a function for $y$ if for every $x$ there is at most one pair $(x,y)$ which satisfies the equation.

So one way of figuring out whether an equation represents a function is to view it as an equation in $y$ treating $x$ as a parameter. If that equation has a unique solution no matter the value of $x$ then the equation represents a function and otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: Okay, and how do I go about ascertaining this? Is there any quick way of doing so?

Comment: Assad - the defintion of a function is rather abstract, which is why you are getting answers like these. There is no "one-size-fits-all" formula you can use - just think about the variety of functions out there. As a more concrete example, there is no "quick" test to see if a number is prime, you need to check the factors using some sort of sieve. You will need to verify that, for each particular case, it is is many-to-one or one-to-one when mapping from arguments to function values.

Comment: @Assad If you have in mind "standard functions" there are several things you can in various special cases though I know of no general algorithm. Is there some specific case you're interested in (we may be able to say more about that).

Comment: Thanks guys, I understand it better now

Answer (score 0):

An "equation" $f(x,y)=0$ in the first place defines a *set*, namely  the set 
$$S=\bigl\{(x,y)\in{\rm dom}(f)\ \bigm|\ f(x,y)=0\bigr\}$$ of points $(x,y)\in{\rm dom}(f)\subset X\times Y$ that satisfy the given equation.

When for a suitable window $$U\times V\subset X\times Y$$ we can prove that for all $x\in U$ there is exactly one $y\in V$ with $(x,y)\in S$ then we say that the equation $f(x,y)=0$ *defines implicitly* a function
$$\psi:\quad U\to V,\qquad x\mapsto \psi(x):= {\rm extr}\{y\in V \ |\ f(x,y)=0\ \}\ .$$
Here the operator ${\rm extr}$ extracts from a singleton set $\{y\}$ its unique element $y$.

When $f$ is given as an explicit expression in the variables $x$ and $y$ then in many cases it is possible to exhibit such $\psi$'s explicitly by solving the equation $f(x,y)=0$ algebraically. But in each case one has to take care about the exact domain $U$ and range $V$ of such a $\psi$.